# How to change only the date portion of a DateTime, while keeping the time portion?

Tags: c#, datetime

I use many DateTime in my code. I want to change those DateTimes to my specific date and keep
time.

```
1. "2012/02/02 06:00:00" => "2015/12/12 : 06:00:00"
2. "2013/02/02 12:00:00" => "2015/12/12 : 12:00:00"
```

I use this style to change, but it seem not the good way and I want to ask have any way to achieve this task.

```
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(2015,12,12,oldDateTime.Hour,oldDateTime.Minute,0);
```

Comment: What formula do you use to calculate the new year, month, and day, or are you just trying to change all dates to have the same date part with the original time part?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "not the good way"? What is wrong with the current implementation?

Comment: While your code does show how you are creating a new datetime object, it does not show the context of your question. for example, are you trying to print them out in that specific format to the console or screen? Where do you get the first part of the value from? I am sure that with a little more information a lot of people would be able to guide you correctly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the information you have given, I think this method is fine. If you want to avoid rewriting the `oldDateTime.Hour,oldDateTime.Minute,0` piece often, you could create your own static class to simplify the method calls.

In your regular application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime newDateTime = MyDateTimeUtil.CreateDateFromTime(2015, 12, 12, time);
    }
}
```

The static class that creates the `DateTime` value:

```
public static class MyDateTimeUtil
{
    public static DateTime CreateDateFromTime(int year, int month, int day, DateTime time)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, month, day, time.Hour, time.Minute, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank grovesNL! It is a good idea with your helper class. So with this example it mean that in c# doesn't have any method to do that right?

Comment: @borrom: Yes, this is a fairly specialized request, so I wouldn't expect the `System.DateTime` class to include this kind of method by default. All of the possible `DateTime` constructors are listed in [the MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 36):

A better way that preserves the seconds, milliseconds and smaller parts of the time would be:

```
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(2015,12,12) + oldDateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Or you could make an extension method to apply a new Date to an existing DateTime and, at the same time, not trust the new date to be without a TimeOfDay on it:-

```
public static DateTime WithDate (this DateTime datetime, DateTime newDate)
{
   return newDate.Date + datetime.TimeOfDay;
}
```

IMHO `DateTime` is one of the weakest parts of .NET. For example, a `TimeSpan` is not the same as a `TimeOfDay` nor can it represent a 'TimePeriod' (in months) - these are three separate concepts and mixing them up was a poor choice. Moving to `DateTimeOffset` is generally preferred or to the excellent Noda time library.

Comment: I did some quick benchmarks and found that this method takes 1/6 of the time it takes using the `DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond)` constructor. Also it's about 6% faster than using `newDate.Date.AddTicks(datetime.TimeOfDay.Ticks)`. So basically, use this. :)

Comment: Performance is a good thing to look at, however you should consider that you mix date types. I suggest testing for DateKind manipulating dates

Comment: Beware this method may return unexpected "Date Kind"