# Can we add date and time values to a DateTime variable separately?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to assign `Date` and `Time` values to a `DateTime` variable separately. Is it possible?

I have a `DateTime` variable named `currentDate`. I need to assign a `Date` value to it from a `DateTime` variable `start`, and the `Time` value from another `DateTime` variable called `outTime`.

Let's say `start` has `4/2/2018 10:00:00` as the value stored in it. And, `outTime` has `4/4/2018 16:00:00` as the value stored in it. Thus, my `currentDate` value should be `4/2/2018 16:00:00` where you can see that `4/2/2018` came from `start` and `16:00:00` came from `outTime`.

I am new to this and I was completely unsure if we could even do this or not.

**Edit - Code Snippet**

This is how I am doing it. However, I am getting an error on `outTime.TimeOfDay` which says: `Cannot implicitly convert type System.TimeSpan to System.DateTime`

```
currentDate = start.Date;
currentDate = outTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: Just adjust the day, month and year manually?

Comment: What type do you want to have for `currentDate` and `outTime`? If it's string, you can simply use `ToString()` overload to extract date and time

Comment: I tried doing that. It gave me an error: `Cannot implicitly convert type `System.TimeSpan` to `System.DateTime`. I used `.TimeOfDay` to access the `Time` part of the `DateTime` variable.

Comment: All variables are of type `DateTime` @AkashKC

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26708089/2457029) is exactly what you need

Comment: @maccettura Could you have a look at the code snippet that I added.

Comment: @Dashamlav the link I posted is exactly what you need to solve it.  The code you just added wont work and I am not sure why you think it will.

Comment: Thank you @maccettura The solution in the link worked! And, I understood what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change only the date portion of a DateTime, while keeping the time portion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707526/how-to-change-only-the-date-portion-of-a-datetime-while-keeping-the-time-portio)

Comment: @maccettura Since the link you posted helped me solve my problem, could you post an answer to this question so that I can mark it as correct? It will be helpful for other users as well.

Comment: @Dashamlav ideally this question would be closed as a duplicate since its an exact duplicate of the question I linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding the `TimeOfDay` part to the `Date` part using `DateTime.Add()`?

```
var date = new DateTime(2018, 1, 5, 20, 0, 0);
var time = new DateTime(2018, 3, 2, 15, 0, 0);

DateTime combined = date.Date.Add(time.TimeOfDay);
```

Results in

> 1/5/2018 3:00:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
like below

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DateTime date = new DateTime(2018,04,04);
            DateTime dateandTime = new DateTime(date.Year,date.Month,date.Day , 16,00,00);

            Console.WriteLine(dateandTime);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
DateTime meetingAppt = new DateTime(2018, 4, 4, 16, 0, 0);
```

You can access to hour only writting

```
meetingAppt.Hour;
meetingAppt.Minute;
```

But at the same time create new one and only use to date

```
meetingAppt.Year;
meetingAppt.Month;
meetingAppt.Day;
```

It's help you?